# Please suggest a better transition phrase as compared to "Coming to"

Tags: phrases, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Excerpt from my essay:

> Coming to my industrial experience, I am currently working in...

My professor's comment on my essay:

> I think you want to transition to industrial experience from undergrad
>   exp... but use ***a better starting phrase*** maybe."

Can someone suggest a better transition phrase than "***Coming to***"?

Comment: In a discurse, consider: "Now, to turn to ..." or "Now, to move on to ...". In a resume, transition is not useful. In a motivation letter to apply to a job, the most appropriate transition formula will depend on the context.

Comment: i copied it wrong. In my draft, it is 'currently'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several phrases you might use. I suggest **"as for"** or **"as to"**

**As for** my industrial experience,I am currently working in.....".

> - [**as for**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20for) - with regard to :  concerning. "As for the others, they'll arrive later."
> - [**as to**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20to) -  as for, about.  "at a loss as to how to explain the error"

Answer (score 0):

how about:

> Since graduating from X in 2015 I've been working at Y doing Z...